# Loop Json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

i have this kind of json array

```
[result] => success
    [totalresults] => 20
    [startnumber] => 0
    [numreturned] => 20
    [invoices] => Array
        (
            [invoice] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2014088828
                            [userid] => 1
                            [firstname] => Rony
                            [lastname] => Raymaekers
                            [companyname] => Raymaekers Rony
                            [invoicenum] => 
                            [date] => 2014-11-19
                            [duedate] => 2014-12-03
                            [datepaid] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [subtotal] => 49.59
                            [credit] => 0.00
                            [tax] => 10.41
                            [tax2] => 0.00
                            [total] => 60.00
                            [taxrate] => 21.00
                            [taxrate2] => 0.00
                            [status] => Unpaid
                            [paymentmethod] => paypal
                            [notes] => 
                            [currencycode] => EUR
                            [currencyprefix] => €
                            [currencysuffix] => EUR
                        )
```

I would like to have the Invoice listed on html table

id, duedate, status, paymentmethod

Please help how to loop this array

i have tried

```
$invoice = json_decode($invoices);
    foreach($invoices as $keys) {
         foreach($keys as $invoice => $kom) {
           echo $kom['id'];

      }

      }
```

but does not works

Comment: Can you provide the actual JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error its

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

also i dont think your looping on the correct thing

```
$array['invoices']['invoice']
```

should be the array in the foreach from the look of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($invoices);

foreach($data['invoices'] as $invoice){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>{$invoice['id']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$invoice['user_id']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$invoice['firstname']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$invoice['lastname']}</td>";
   // and so on
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: @lainard could you please try var_dump(json_decode($invoices)); and give me the result